# How to translate the word match?

Tags: traduction

As in something that resembles or fits together.

For instance:

- Her dress matches her purse;
- It is difficult to match your skills in tennis;
- etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Depending of the context, *correspondre*, *égaler*, or *être à la hauteur/au niveau* can be good translations:

***Correspondre***:

> Son habillement **correspond** à ses revenus.

or

> Votre offre **correspond** tout à fait à mes besoins. 
> (*Your offers does perfectly match my needs.*)

***Égaler***:

> Il est difficile **de t'égaler** au tennis.

***Être à la hauteur***:

> Il travaille dur, mais son salaire **n'est pas à la hauteur** de son implication. 
> (*He is a hard worker, but his salary doesn't match his dedication*.)

- This is not a comprehensive list as this is really context-dependent. To my knowledge, no French verb is as generic as *to match*.
- And quite frequently I can hear the anglicism *matcher*, in France. You might be led to hear that, especially at work:

> *<s>Ton implication et mes attentes matchent, c'est bien !</s> 
> (*You dedication matches my expectations. That's good!*)

This is actually bad French, so this should be discouraged.

Comment: être à la hauteur can also have a positive meaning. Le résultat est à la hauteur de ses attentes.

Comment: @LudovicC. It may be used a positive way as well, yes: "L'offre est à la hauteur de la demande, inutile de produire plus".

Comment: @LudovicC. Re-reading my post I see what you mean. It was unclear, I have edited it.

Answer (score 3):

If by

- Her dress matches her purse;

you are speaking of color and style (and so *purse* is not here as an euphemism for wealth), one would say

> Sa robe est assortie à son sac.

To find a french term which *match* a desired meaning in the large set of meanings of *to match*, I'll recommend again [this site](http://dico.isc.cnrs.fr/fr/index_tr.html) (sadly, I'm unable to give a direct URL to the map it generates) which gives 60 or 70 French terms and maps them along about the same number of English words more precise than *match*.

Answer (score 1):

One can think of the expression **"être à la hauteur de"** to express the idea of the verb to match. But I am not sure that an *universal* expression could be found to translate it and to give back the same meaning in all the context. In some cases one can use the verbs **"égaler"**, **"être comparable à"**, **"équivaloir"** (this one can be tricky to conjugate) etc.